# issue connecting to kernel in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Hi new to this so apologies if this has been asked before however I cant see a definitive way of fixing this.

I had installed a tensorflow environment as per the attached guide
https://priyanka-dandale.medium.com/how-to-create-a-tensorflow-environment-in-jupyter-notebook-and-use-it-e3815002c031

Seemed to install ok with no issues.

However when I went to use it cannot connect to the Kernel for some reason?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWaef.png)

Any assistance or things to try would be appreciated

```
        To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/michael.burnett/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-29156-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=30cf96d443d97f7836bbeb7bf65388624076e1f0a51dc5f2
     or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=30cf96d443d97f7836bbeb7bf65388624076e1f0a51dc5f2
[I 18:43:02.262 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 18:43:05.968 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2, name: tensorflow-environment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
[I 18:43:08.954 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
[I 18:43:11.983 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
[I 18:43:14.996 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
[I 18:43:18.012 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\michael.burnett\.conda\envs\tensorflow-environment\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
[W 18:43:21.049 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 18:43:21.053 NotebookApp] Kernel 7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2 died, removing from map.
[W 18:44:05.905 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2
[E 18:44:08.631 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2)
[W 18:44:09.686 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2/channels?session_id=0ce1ed9df95442e4b070a5bd1da4b15c (::1): Kernel does not exist: 7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2
[W 18:44:09.712 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2/channels?session_id=0ce1ed9df95442e4b070a5bd1da4b15c (::1) 28.970000ms referer=None
[W 18:44:11.732 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 7a742942-da07-4046-83cd-fb28cf7a20f2:0ce1ed9df95442e4b070a5bd1da4b15c
[I 18:45:06.031 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled7.ipynb
```

Comment: From the terminal where you started the jupyter notebook, do you get any error message or similar?

Comment: hi no it starts normally then when trying to connect then the error message appears after a few minutes

Comment: Are you starting the notebook from the anaconda navigator or by typing `jupyter notebook` into the terminal? If you are doing the first, can you try the second and see if an error message shows in the terminal when your browser shows you the error message you have shown in your question?

Comment: so this is the error i can see ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Please put the full output into your question by hitting the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71483881/edit) button and then copy-paste the terminal output into the question. Then mark it all and click the code format button `{}`

Comment: have added the code now in the top